# Updating a nested item aws-dynamo-db (AWS SDK for Java 2.0)

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a nested domain object which has a structure like this :

```java
class Domain {
//range key
 private final Integer Id; 
//hash key
 private final String accountId;
 //some  fields and this list nested //(below)
 private final List<Integer> list ;
}
```

Tried to follow this sample [https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/UpdateItem.java

So I have already a saved domain. I want to update with nested child list as null . So basically I am looking for partial update.

```java
    Integer Id=1000;
    String accountId="1001";
     list = null;
```

But I see no updates happening...what could be the reason. Thr code below is just copy paste of sample in documentation.

Code :

```java
item_key.put(COLUMN_NAME_ACCOUNT_ID,
                item_key.put(COLUMN_NAME__ID, AttributeValue.builder().n(String.valueOf(domain.getId())).build());

        HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate> updated_values = new HashMap<String, AttributeValueUpdate>();
        List<AttributeValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
        updated_values.put(COLUMN_NAME_LIST, AttributeValueUpdate.builder()
                .value(AttributeValue.builder().l(list).build())
                .action(AttributeAction.PUT)
                .build());
        UpdateItemRequest request = UpdateItemRequest.builder()
                .tableName(tableName)
                .key(item_key)
                .attributeUpdates(updated_values)
                .build();
        UpdateItemResponse response = dynamoDbAsyncClient.updateItem(request).getNow(null);
        Domain updated = mapToDomain(response.attributes());
        return updated;`
```

Comment: You should use `AttributeAction.DELETE` to set a list to `null`